# context and custom adapter

Tags: android-asynctask, this, adapter, android-context

I need some help with `Asynctask` and a custom adapter.
I have an `asynctask` that gets data by parsing. Then I have to put them in a `ListView`. 
I created a Custom adapter, but I have some problem with context. I'm sure this has a very simple solution, but I can't understand what actually **context** is!
The problem is illustrated in eclipse:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(final List<String> list) {
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listavvisi);

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(**this**, R.layout.rowcustom, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and I pass my list to `customadapter`

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Avviso> {
private Context context;

  public CustomAdapter(**Context** **context**, int textViewResourceId, List<Avviso> Strings) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, Strings);
}
```

What **context** I need when calling a `New Customadapter...`?

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question.
So, I had to use "javaclass.this" instead of "context"